# Windows GDI Differences between Win98 and WinXP (or Later)

Tags: windows, gdi

I have a game (of which I don't have the source code) that runs well on Win98, but on WinXP or later (i.e. WinXP/7/8/10), the text in certain scenarios is missing. BTW: This has nothing to do with language or locale, since I set them to the same values on both Win98 and WinXP (or later).

The game itself does not check Windows version, so I am pretty sure this problem is caused by the internal change in Windows GDI ever since Win98.

I couldn't find any Microsoft official document describing the changes or differences of GDI between each Windows version. Does anyone have similar experience and could possibly shed some light on this issue?

PS: I've also tried to override the Windows version in compatibility settings to Windows 98 or even Windows 95, but none of them helped.

PPS: I tried to debug this issue and I could see the text was indeed printed onto GDI bitmap, but somehow not correctly rendered onto the screen. This is the part I couldn't figure out since the game runs the same code on both Win98 and WinXP (or later).

PPPS: I spent more time on debugging and found the problem was in StretchDIBits() with SRCPAINT. The source DIB is white text on black background. This functions returns without error, but somehow not actually rendered onto the destination DC. When I change the mode from SRCPAINT to SRCCOPY, the text does show up (the backgrouond is also overwritten with black, which is expected). It seems something is internally wrong with SRCPAINT on WinXP or later.

[image]

Comment: You mention that you tried to debug it and it led you to some conclutions. You should describe in detail what you have done and what you have observed.

Comment: GDI on 9x is 16-bit.

Comment: Yes, I also thought maybe it had something to do with the 16-bit handler of GDI resources in Win98, but I couldn't figure out how that could affect the logic that picks a bitmap.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anyway, I finally found out the root cause myself.

On Win98, When calling StretchDIBits() with SRCPAINT mode, the [xSrc,ySrc] of a source DIB always treats the lower-left as source origin.

However, on WinXP or later, when calling StretchDIBits() with SRCPAINT mode, the [xSrc,ySrc] of the source DIB treats the origin differently. If the DIB is a bottom-up one (positive height), then the source origin is at lower-left; if the DIB is a top-down one (negative height), then the source origin is at upper-left.

Comment: Nice find. You are allowed to accept your own answer...

Comment: There are other places where top-down is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Windows XP's compatibility mode? See http://what-when-how.com/windows-xp/using-program-compatibility-modes-in-windows-xp/ for an example.

The reason I ask this is that it's an important step in finding out where the issue lies. If it works when the shim (i.e, compatibility mode) is applied, then the issue probably lies with a GDI change as you said. If not, either Windows XP's compatibility mode does not work for this specific issue or the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes, I tried but compatibility settings didn't help. It must be some internal change inside GDI system.